# show Authenticated user in select option vuejs

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a form where I want to fill the select options with some users and if the option id is equals the logged user then it will set as the selected option.

```
<div class="flex flex-col mb-4 md:w-full">
    <label for="seller_id">Vendedor</label>
    <select v-model="registration.seller_id" name="seller_id">
          <option disabled>Vendedor</option>
          <option v-for="seller in sellers" :key="seller" :value="seller.id" v-bind:selected="seller.id == this.$page.props.user.id">{{ seller.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
export default {
props: {
    sellers: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
},
data() {
    return {
        step:1,
        showModal: false,
        registration:{
            seller_id: null,
            name:null,
            email:null,
            rg:null,
            cpf:null,
            rural_productor_code:null,
            birthday:null,
            street:null,
            city:null,
            state:null,
        }
    }
   },
};
</script>
```

When i print the condition inside the option, it shows true, but the current user is not selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you are keeping your current user state. On

```
created() {
// You assign your logged Seller Id or null if no user signed in
this.registration.seller_id = yourLoggedUser.id || null
}
```